# Java Swing adding action listener to combo box

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Combo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   public Combo() {
    setSize(500,500);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    String[] country=new String[]{"INDIA","AMERICA","NIGERIA"};
    JComboBox comboBox=new JComboBox<String>(country);
    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    comboBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(comboBox);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox comboBox=(JComboBox) e.getSource();
    String s1=(String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String s2=(String) comboBox.getActionCommand();

   System.out.println(s1);
   System.out.println(s2);
 }
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   new Combo();
 }
}
```

This code is perfectly compiling however while running the code the comboBox isnt working....it doesnt show on the swing :( help

Comment: Maybe you should add before `setVisible` or call `revalidate`.

Comment: like @GáborBakos said call setvisible last after the line `add(comboBox);`

Comment: thanks it worked LOL

Comment: The correct solution for your problem is running your program from the EDT, the other thing is just a paving.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your program from the EDT Thread:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      new Combo();
    }
  });
}
```

In swing, every manipulation on swing objects should happen inside the EDT. See the [swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java).

The EDT is the event dispatcher thread. In this thread, swing does all its wonders: Processing click events to pass it to your listeners, repainting just everything. Since swing is not thread safe, you should not access swing objects outside the EDT. There are a plethora of resources about the EDT, example the Swing [tutorial from sun/oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: Actually I am new to java have been learning it for 20 days only that too moderately so i have no idea what EDT is :( sounds dumb but i ll go right now and check and read about it :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, running the program in EDT thread is the right way, however if you want to do it differently (although it's less recommended) you can call the methods after you've updated the values:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Combo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        public Combo() {
        setSize(500,500);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    String[] country=new String[]{"INDIA","AMERICA","NIGERIA"};
    JComboBox comboBox=new JComboBox<String>(country);
    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    comboBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(comboBox);
    revalidate();
    repaint();

  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox comboBox=(JComboBox) e.getSource();
    String s1=(String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String s2=(String) comboBox.getActionCommand();

   System.out.println(s1);
   System.out.println(s2);
 }
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   new Combo();
 }
}
```

Comment: I studied paint method in applets however there is no paint method in swings.....

Comment: `you can call the methods after you've updated the values:` - not only is this a bad recommendation, the order of the code is wrong. The order should be revalidate() (to invoke the layout manager) and then repaint() (to paint the components at there new location and size).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
public class Combo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public Combo() {

String[] country=new String[]{"INDIA","AMERICA","NIGERIA"};
JComboBox comboBox=new JComboBox<String>(country);
comboBox.setEditable(true);
comboBox.addActionListener(this);
add(comboBox);

setSize(500,500);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please include an explanation along with your code to provide the best possible answer.